# Bundles arent unpacking only on one server

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

Have a little problem with bundles on site.There are source code of creating and including bundles

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Administration").Include("~/Content/Administration.css"));
```

And on View

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/Administration")
```

so on test server all OK,but on main(production),my bundle hadnt been loaded.What i can do with this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

to debug css on test server,and find error after minification/now all ok